# Checar campos CPF e Email antes de enviar pro banco (PHP)

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, sql-insert

Boa noite! Gostaria de saber como posso implementar uma função (talvez?) ou algum método pra checar se os campos cpf e e-mail no meu código já existem no banco antes de cadastrá-los, e se existir, exibir uma mensagem por exemplo: "CPF já cadastrado!".

Segue o código:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../banco/conexao.php';

$SendCadPet = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SendCadPet', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($SendCadPet) {
    $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $cpf = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $endereco = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'endereco', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $cidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cidade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $estado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'estado', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $telefone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'telefone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $senha = crypt(addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)), $security_salt);
    $imagem = '../avatar/default.png';

    //Inserir
    $res = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, cpf, endereco, cidade, estado, telefone, email, usuario, senha, imagem, nivel) 
    VALUES (:nome, :cpf, :endereco,
    :cidade, :estado, :telefone, :email, :usuario, :senha, :imagem, :nivel)";

    $insert = $pdo->prepare($res);
    $insert->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
    $insert->bindParam(':cpf', $cpf);
    $insert->bindParam(':endereco', $endereco);
    $insert->bindParam(':cidade', $cidade);
    $insert->bindParam(':estado', $estado);
    $insert->bindParam(':telefone', $telefone);
    $insert->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $insert->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
    $insert->bindParam(':senha', $senha);
    $insert->bindParam(':imagem', $imagem);
    $insert->bindValue(':nivel', "2");

    if ($insert->execute()) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-success'>Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!</div></center>";
        header("Location: ../views/Cadastros.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-warning'>Falha no Cadastro!</div></center>";
        header("Location: ../views/Cadastros.php");
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-warning'>Falha no Cadastro!</div></center>";
    header("Location: ../views/Cadastros.php");
}
```

**OBS.: O include_once está incluindo a conexão ao banco.**

Comment: Basta verificar se o CPF já existe no banco correto? CPF é unico.

Comment: Isso mesmo.....

Comment: Mesmo verificando antes, verifique também após o INSERT. É que pode ocorrer que outro processo em paralelo insira o mesmo CPF momentos antes ("concorrência de processos").

Answer (score 1):

- Em primeiro lugar, você tem que criar um índice **UNIQUE** para a coluna `cpf` e `email`. Isto garante a unicidade.

  Portanto, se houver uma tentativa de inserir uma linha duplicada, o Mecanismo de Banco de Dados retornará uma mensagem de erro indicando que a restrição **UNIQUE** foi violada e a linha não será adicionada à tabela.
- Use esses campos com **Not Null**

  O MySQL permite vários NULLs em uma coluna com uma restrição **UNIQUE**. Isso não é verdade para todos os bancos de dados.

  A restrição **NOT NULL** garante que uma coluna não admita valores NULL. Isto significa que será abortada uma operação de INSERT que coloque um valor NULL nessa coluna.
- Sobre o código em si, as considerações estão comentadas nele

  ```
   /* ###### A condicional não está correta. Vai sempre ser redirecionado para a ../views/Cadastros.php
             e não vai ser possível fazer inserts. No else tem que fazer algo que não seja um redirecionamento.
             Exemplo, mostrar uma mensagem de erro.
   ######################################################################################################### */

   if ($insert->execute()) {
       $_SESSION['msg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-success'>Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!</div></center>";
       header("Location: index.php");
   } else {

       // ##### aqui seria politicamente correto tratar os erros ##############################################
               $array = $insert->errorInfo();

                // vai mostrar um array que mostra tipo de erro
               //print_r($array);

               //exemplos de erros MySQL:

               //Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1048 [2] => Column 'cpf' cannot be null ) 
               //Array ( [0] => 23000 [1] => 1062 [2] => Duplicate entry '000.000.001-01' for key 'cpf' ) 

               //e de acordo com o erro emitir a mensagem adequada.

       //######################################################################################################

         /* #### isso, como dito acima, não está correto #################################### */

           //$_SESSION['msg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-warning'>Falha no Cadastro 1!</div></center>";
           //header("Location: index.php");

       //######################################################################################################
   }
  ```

Comment: Vou tentar e dou um feedback!

Comment: Leo, implementei o seu codigo no meu, porém é como se ele não consultasse o CPF, ele ta cadastrando mesmo possuindo um CPF igual.

Comment: @Alicia, pra descobrir o que está errado vc deveria postar todo o codigo, conexão e html

Comment: Ok! Jaja posto.

Comment: Leo, é necessario fazer essa conexao com o banco sendo que eu já tenho um include com a conexao?

Comment: @Woss, me responda, qual das 3 não pode ser considerada uma operação atômica -  tocar a campainha - encher um copo de água - desligar a luz

Comment: @Woss,  carro=='sim'?cachorro="não" :cachorro="sim". As respostas sugeridas tb não resolvem completamente. O não insert pode estar ocorrendo devido a outros erros. Tratando tudo completamente  equivale a dar um PRÉDIO Isso sem considerar que uma resposta tá com MySQL* já em desuso

Answer (score 1):

Oi, para que nunca exista um CPF REPETIDO, você deve deixar no BD a coluna como CHAVE UNICA (UNIQUE KEY) dessa maneira, você não precisaria testar no banco com este select, o próprio BD faria as validações e basta o seu código tratar os erros do banco, não se importando com as regras definidas pelo DBA.

Comment: Então, eu fiz essas regras no banco, porém não fazia ideia de como retornar essas validações em mensagem, sou iniciante no php! Tem alguma ideia que possa me ajudar?

Comment: if(!$insert->execute()){
    print_r($insert->errorInfo());
}
Isso é o básico, vai dar as mensagens como vem do banco, você pode criar uma função para tratamento de erro, que receba o error number e mostre uma mensagem mais amigavel ou em português, conforme seu caso. e que pode dar a saída (die) em caso de impossibilidade de continuar como por exemplo se houve uma violação da chave, ou se a conexão do banco caiu....

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once '../banco/conexao.php';

$SendCadPet = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'SendCadPet', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($SendCadPet) {
    $nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $cpf = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $endereco = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'endereco', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $cidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cidade', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $estado = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'estado', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $telefone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'telefone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    $usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $senha = crypt(addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)), $security_salt);
    $imagem = '../avatar/default.png';


     if (validaCampoVazio($email,$cpf)) 
     {
       echo "errorCampoVazios";
     }
       elseif (validaEmail($email))
     {
       echo "errorEmail";
     }
       elseif (!ValidaCpf($cpf)) 
     {
       echo "errorCpf";
     }
       else
     {



    //Inserir
    $res = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, cpf, endereco, cidade, estado, telefone, email, usuario, senha, imagem, nivel) 
    VALUES (:nome, :cpf, :endereco,
    :cidade, :estado, :telefone, :email, :usuario, :senha, :imagem, :nivel)";

    $insert = $pdo->prepare($res);
    $insert->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
    $insert->bindParam(':cpf', $cpf);
    $insert->bindParam(':endereco', $endereco);
    $insert->bindParam(':cidade', $cidade);
    $insert->bindParam(':estado', $estado);
    $insert->bindParam(':telefone', $telefone);
    $insert->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $insert->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
    $insert->bindParam(':senha', $senha);
    $insert->bindParam(':imagem', $imagem);
    $insert->bindValue(':nivel', "2");

    if ($insert->execute()) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-success'>Usuário Cadastrado com Sucesso!</div></center>";
        header("Location: ../views/Cadastros.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-warning'>Falha no Cadastro!</div></center>";
        header("Location: ../views/Cadastros.php");
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<center><div class='alert alert-warning'>Falha no Cadastro!</div></center>";
    header("Location: ../views/Cadastros.php");
}
}


Funcoes adicionais
      // funcao para validacao do email
        function validaEmail($email){
          // Verifica se o email NÃO bate no requisitos
          if (filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return false;
          }else {
            return true;
          }
        }

 
        // funcao para validar se os campos estão vazios
        function validaCampoVazio($email,$cpf){
          // verifica se tem campo vazio
            if (empty($email) || empty($cpf)){
              return true;
            }else {
              return false;
            }
        }

        // funcao valida CPF
        function ValidaCpf($cpf){
          // Extrai somente os números
          $cpf = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/is', '', $cpf );
          // Verifica se foi informado todos os digitos corretamente
          if (strlen($cpf) != 11) {
            return false;
          }
          // Verifica se foi informada uma sequência de digitos repetidos. Ex: 111.111.111-11
          if (preg_match('/(\d)\1{10}/', $cpf)) {
            return false;
          }
          // Faz o calculo para validar o CPF
          for ($t = 9; $t < 11; $t++) {
            for ($d = 0, $c = 0; $c < $t; $c++) {
              $d += $cpf{$c} * (($t + 1) - $c);
            }
            $d = ((10 * $d) % 11) % 10;
            if ($cpf{$c} != $d) {
              return false;
            }
          }
          return true;
        }
```

Resumo do que adicionei:
-> Após a variável chamar via POST, você ja entra em um laço que envolve todo o código;
-> Ele faz a validação de se os campos estão vazios;
-> Verifica o CPF, utilizando o cálculo para validação;
-> Verifica o Email também.

As funções estão comentadas no final do código.

O return das funções, aconselho você a receber eles com AJAX, sem precisar recarregar a página, você deve igualar ela ao return, comparando-a, e depois pode fazer um alert, ou apenas retornar uma div.

Caso queira, eu utilizo um plugin para javascript, para estilizar esses alerts, chamado SweetAlert2, vou deixa o link dele aqui: https://sweetalert2.github.io/ , é bem fácil de usar.

Se quiser dar uma olhada na documentação do AJAX: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: Vou tentar e dou um retorno!